# Node.js and Mongoose - Cast to date failed for value (filtering created_at dates)

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

Im creating a search endpoint that will filter the results via a date range.

```
http://0.0.0.0:3000/api/v1/transactions/search?endDate=2018-10-03T14:07:03.382Z
```

So the above, wants to search all transactions up to and equal the created_at date.

```
console.log(req.query.endDate) // 2018-10-03T14:07:03.382Z
```

This is part of the query i build

```
created_at = {
   gte: startDate,
   lte: endDate,
};

    let query = {
    ...query,
    created_at
}

const transactions = await Transaction.find(query);
```

This is what my query string looks like

```
{ created_at: { lte: '2018-10-03T14:07:03.382Z' } }
```

However i get the following error.

> Cast to date failed for value "{ lte: '2018-10-03T14:07:03.382Z' }" at
>   path "created_at" for model "Transaction""

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Short answer**: It should be `$lte`, not `lte`.

**Long answer**:

There is pretty good tutorial what you need to know about [Working With Dates](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/tutorials/dates.html) in mongoose.

Let's say you have a schema where you have declared field with type of `Date`.

> When you create a document, Mongoose will cast the value to a native JavaScript date using the Date() constructor.
>
> An invalid date will lead to a CastError when you validate the document.

Because of missing `$` sign, your query is accepted like "Find me transactions where `created_at` is an object equal `{ lte: '2018-10-03T14:07:03.382Z' }`".

Mongoose will try to convert this value to date.

```
new Date({ lte: '2018-10-03T14:07:03.382Z' });
```

Obviously it's not a valid date, and this expression will fail with `CastError`.

Comment: Cast to date failed for value "{ lte: 2018-10-03T14:07:03.382Z }" at path "created_at" for model "Transaction""

Comment: Also missed `$` sign, just updated answer, try again plz

Comment: yes it worked ty so much. Btw i dont need to do new Date if its already a iso string

Comment: Even better for you :)

Comment: Old answer was not very accurate. Here I replaced it with more detailed explanation